# How to use CallBase method on mocked Fluentvalidation Validator using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, fluentvalidation

The goal is to verify wether the validation was invoked using the right ruleset whilst still invoking the actual validation (base method).

The current implementation gives a DynamicProxy2 exception that I do not understand.

```
public static void SetupWithExpectedRuleset<T>(this Mock<IValidator<T>> validator, params string[] expectedRuleSet)
{
    validator.Setup(x => x.Validate(It.Is<ValidationContext<T>>(ctx => IsExpectedRuleSet(ctx, expectedRuleSet)))).CallBase();
}

private static bool IsExpectedRuleSet<T>(ValidationContext<T> context, IEnumerable<string> expectedRuleSet)
{
    return (context.Selector as FluentValidation.Internal.RulesetValidatorSelector)?.RuleSets.SequenceEqual(expectedRuleSet) == true;
}
```

The exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException: This is a DynamicProxy2 error: The interceptor attempted to 'Proceed' for method 'FluentValidation.Results.ValidationResult Validate(FluentValidation.IValidationContext)' which has no target. When calling method without target there is no implementation to 'proceed' to and it is the responsibility of the interceptor to mimic the implementation (set return value, out arguments etc)
```

Comment: "The actual validation (base method)" doesn't exist here, you're trying to call it on the `IValidator<T>` interface. Are you using default interface implementations? Without a concrete class there's no base method to call.